# wordpress - how to send a popup message to all users on the website

Tags: wordpress

I am playing with the WordPress for the first time ever. In my current project, I have a problem to solve.

**I want a user to receive popup messages with some extra information that is related to the website they are browsing. Creation of this message and targeting is manual action made by the site administrator.**

So the user stories sound more or less like that:

> I, as a User, want to receive a popup message about new information
>   related to the page I am browsing. So that I will know about all the
>   new information that may be of interest to me.

From Website Administrator/Owner

> I, as an Administrator, wants to be able to send a message to all of
>   the users (logged and not logged) that are currently on my website. So
>   that they will know about some additional information that may be
>   interesting for them.

as well as

> I, as an Administrator, wants to be able to send a message to the
>   users that are currently on my website at page A. So that they will
>   know about some additional information that may be interesting for
>   them.

And I am blocked. I do not have a clue how to put this in a google's query, and what kind of modules should I be looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a brain freeze for few days apparently - the perfect solution for it is:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-maker

and triggering the popup per URL contains.